# PAYPAL IPN Listner

Tags: ssl, curl, paypal, paypal-pdt

I have been pulling my hair out trying to get this to work for over a week. I have even purchased an SSL cert for the domain.

I keep getting the error:
[2016-03-14 18:07 Europe/London] Can not connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: SSL connect error

Heres my code.

```
                <?php
            // CONFIG: Enable debug mode. This means we'll log requests into 'ipn.log' in the same directory.
            // Especially useful if you encounter network errors or other intermittent problems with IPN (validation).
            // Set this to 0 once you go live or don't require logging.
            define("DEBUG", 1);
            // Set to 0 once you're ready to go live
            define("USE_SANDBOX", 1);
            define("LOG_FILE", "ipn.log");

            error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Test message: "  . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);

            // Read POST data
            // reading posted data directly from $_POST causes serialization
            // issues with array data in POST. Reading raw POST data from input stream instead.
            $raw_post_data = file_get_contents('php://input');
            $raw_post_array = explode('&', $raw_post_data);
            $myPost = array();
            foreach ($raw_post_array as $keyval) {
                $keyval = explode ('=', $keyval);
                if (count($keyval) == 2)
                    $myPost[$keyval[0]] = urldecode($keyval[1]);
            }
            // read the post from PayPal system and add 'cmd'
            $req = 'cmd=_notify-validate';
            if(function_exists('get_magic_quotes_gpc')) {
                $get_magic_quotes_exists = true;
            }
            foreach ($myPost as $key => $value) {
                if($get_magic_quotes_exists == true && get_magic_quotes_gpc() == 1) {
                    $value = urlencode(stripslashes($value));
                } else {
                    $value = urlencode($value);
                }
                $req .= "&$key=$value";
            }
            // Post IPN data back to PayPal to validate the IPN data is genuine
            // Without this step anyone can fake IPN data
            if(USE_SANDBOX == true) {
                $paypal_url = "https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            } else {
                $paypal_url = "https://www.paypal.com/cgi-bin/webscr";
            }

            //$userAgent = 'Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1) AppleWebKit/537.2 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/22.0.1216.0 Safari/537.2';
            $ch = curl_init($paypal_url);
            if ($ch == FALSE) {
                return FALSE;
            }
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION, CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, $userAgent );
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $req);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);  
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FORBID_REUSE, 1);
            if(DEBUG == true) {
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
                curl_setopt($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT, 1);
            }
            // CONFIG: Optional proxy configuration
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_PROXY, $proxy);
            //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPPROXYTUNNEL, 1);
            // Set TCP timeout to 30 seconds
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, array('Connection: Close'));




            // CONFIG: Please download 'cacert.pem' from "http://curl.haxx.se/docs/caextract.html" and set the directory path
            // of the certificate as shown below. Ensure the file is readable by the webserver.
            // This is mandatory for some environments.


            $res = curl_exec($ch);
            if (curl_errno($ch) != 0) // cURL error
                {
                if(DEBUG == true) { 
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Can not connect to PayPal to validate IPN message: " . curl_error($ch) . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                }
                curl_close($ch);
                exit;
            } else {
                    // Log the entire HTTP response if debug is switched on.
                    if(DEBUG == true) {
                        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP request of validation request:". curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HEADER_OUT) ." for IPN payload: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                        error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "HTTP response of validation request: $res" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                    }
                    curl_close($ch);
            }
            // Inspect IPN validation result and act accordingly
            // Split response headers and payload, a better way for strcmp
            $tokens = explode("\r\n\r\n", trim($res));
            $res = trim(end($tokens));
            if (strcmp ($res, "VERIFIED") == 0) {
                // check whether the payment_status is Completed
                // check that txn_id has not been previously processed
                // check that receiver_email is your PayPal email
                // check that payment_amount/payment_currency are correct
                // process payment and mark item as paid.
                // assign posted variables to local variables
                //$item_name = $_POST['item_name'];
                //$item_number = $_POST['item_number'];
                //$payment_status = $_POST['payment_status'];
                //$payment_amount = $_POST['mc_gross'];
                //$payment_currency = $_POST['mc_currency'];
                //$txn_id = $_POST['txn_id'];
                //$receiver_email = $_POST['receiver_email'];
                //$payer_email = $_POST['payer_email'];

                if(DEBUG == true) {
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Verified IPN: $req ". PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                }
            } else if (strcmp ($res, "INVALID") == 0) {
                // log for manual investigation
                // Add business logic here which deals with invalid IPN messages
                if(DEBUG == true) {
                    error_log(date('[Y-m-d H:i e] '). "Invalid IPN: $req" . PHP_EOL, 3, LOG_FILE);
                }
            }
            ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why you bought an SSL certificate to fix connecting to PayPal.

Try changing

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 2);
```

to

```
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYHOST, 0);
```

My bet is the SSL handshake is failing to the server. Disabling the checks should help clear it up.

Comment: Thanks, Tried that but still get error: SSL connect error  This is driving me up the wall...There must be a reason for this????

Comment: Hmm, try adding `curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSLVERSION, 6);` to your CURL request

Comment: You star !!Thank you, at last it worked. Its only taken  a week of hair pulling.

Comment: I posted a more complete (and on point) answer as to why you have to change this on [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36046067/my-paypal-script-suddenly-stopped-verifying-the-ssl-certificate)